# How do I use ORDER BY/GROUP BY to ignore some expression?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to group together, say column X, ignoring what is inside the bracket

```
      X

aaabbbccc[0]aaabbbccc
aaabbbccc[15]aaabbbccc
aaabbbccc[11]eeefffggg
aaabbbccc[10]eeefffggg
aaabbbccc[17]aaabbbccc
aaabbbccc[19]eeefffggg
```

As,

```
      X

aaabbbccc[0]aaabbbccc
aaabbbccc[15]aaabbbccc
aaabbbccc[17]aaabbbccc
aaabbbccc[10]eeefffggg
aaabbbccc[11]eeefffggg
aaabbbccc[19]eeefffggg
```

However, if I use ORDER BY or GROUP BY, I always get as below.

```
aaabbbccc[0]aaabbbccc
aaabbbccc[10]eeefffggg
aaabbbccc[11]eeefffggg
aaabbbccc[15]aaabbbccc
aaabbbccc[17]aaabbbccc
aaabbbccc[19]eeefffggg
```

Can anyone please suggest how can I overcome this scenerio.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a) some real rows, b) some real SQL oh and usually to exclude rows you use a WHERE clause

Comment: Do you want `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY`? These do quite different things! (From your desired output looks like you want `ORDER BY`)

Answer (score 1):

You can group/order on derived values, though this precludes using index so performance will be abysmal on large tables:

```
SELECT ...
...
GROUP BY CONCAT(
    LEFT(yourfield, LOCATE('[', yourfield)),
    RIGHT(yourfield, LENGTH(yourfield) - LOCATE(']', yourfield))
);
```

**NOTE:** just going off the top of my head, so this most likely won't work, but should give you a basis to work from. Assuming it works, it'd split the string into two parts - before the `[` and after the `]`, put those two pieces together, then group on them, effectively eliminating the `[...]` part.

If you're doing this sort of thing regularly, then I suggest splitting this field into two separate ones, so you have dedicated/permanent 'before' and 'after' fields that can be indexed and grouped/sorted on easier than this ugly monstrosity.

Comment: Thanks. I got this idea and trying to make it work. Will post the result if it works.

Comment: I could trim the lower part by using RIGHT () and LOCATE() and stored that in a temporary table, as you had hinted. Then did the ORDER BY to solve my problem. Thanks a lot for the the idea.